# Where am I wrong in proving that the gradient transforms as a vector under rotations

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose that f is a function of two variables (y and z) only.
Show that the gradient $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} \hat{y} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial z} \hat{z}$ transforms as a vector under rotations.

$$\overline{y} = y \cos{\phi} + z \sin{\phi}$$
$$\overline{z} = -y \sin{\phi} + z \cos{\phi}$$

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \overline{y} = y \cos{\phi} + z \sin{\phi} \\
      \overline{z} = -y \sin{\phi} + z \cos{\phi} \\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \cfrac{\overline{y}- z \sin{\phi}} {\cos{\phi}} = y \\
      \cfrac{\overline{z} + y \sin{\phi}} {\cos{\phi}} = z \\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \cfrac{\partial y} {\partial \overline{y}} =\cfrac{1} {\cos{\phi}} \\
      \cfrac{\partial z} {\partial \overline{z}} =\cfrac{1} {\cos{\phi}} \\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

Using chain rule.
$$
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial \overline{y}} =
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial y}  \cfrac{\partial y} {\partial \overline{y}}
+
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial z}  \cfrac{\partial z} {\partial \overline{y}}
$$

$$
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial \overline{z}} =
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial z}  \cfrac{\partial z} {\partial \overline{z}}
+
\cfrac{\partial f} {\partial y}  \cfrac{\partial y} {\partial \overline{z}}
$$

Comment: Do chain rule instead. It's going to be cleaner than this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Answer from my book said the following $$\cfrac{\partial y} {\partial \overline{y}} =\cos{\phi}$$
     and $$ \cfrac{\partial z} {\partial \overline{z}} =\cos{\phi}$$

Comment: You also have the other partial derivatives that are being omitted that appear in your multivariable chain rule expression.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Could you write down what I am missing?

Comment: When you take the partials $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \bar y}, \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \bar z}$, you assume that $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z}. \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \bar y}$ are both $0$. They are not.